# Nginx не получается отдать статику из flask приложения

Tags: nginx, flask

```
root /home/flaskapp/static/app;

location /images/ {
        try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;

}

location @proxy_to_app {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        # enable this if and only if you use HTTPS
        # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        # we don't want nginx trying to do something clever with
        # redirects, we set the Host: header above already.
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://app_server;
}
```

Из лог файла

> /home/flaskapp/app/static/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"

Возвращает ошибку 404. Где проблема?

Comment: то, что ты видишь в логе никак не относится к показанному куску конфигурации. напиши запрашиваемый ресурс и выкладывай полный конфиг nginx